# Can my laptop handle kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, laptop

I would like to know if my laptop can handle kubuntu. If not, what are my options ?

The informations about my laptop:

- Windows XP,  Version 2002
- Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU
- or Mobile Intel(R) 965 Express Chipset Family
- T5670 @ 1.80GHz
- 789 MHx, 0.99Gb of RAM
- Physical Address Extension

Thank you in advance,

Adam

Answer (score 0):

Your computer can handle it, but it would be quite slow. The main weakness of your computer is your RAM, which I would suggest you to upgrade it at least to 2 Gb; if you can get it to 3Gb or 4Gb, it would be better, and you could easily handle Kubuntu or Ubuntu. Over 4Gb, it is almost Useless.

So, if you want to keep your computer as it is, and have an experience of a fast and reactive Operating system (I mean faster than Windows, which is always too slow for me, but I am really not patient), I would suggest you to go for Xubuntu (XFCE) or Lubuntu (LXDE). They are basically the same as Ubuntu, but with lighter desktop environment. LXDE is lighter than XFCE, but less customizable.

Here are the links for Xubuntu and Lubuntu

http://xubuntu.org/
http://lubuntu.net/

Comment: No matter which distribution you will choose, add as much RAM as possible.

Comment: The distribution matter. On my old P4 with 1 Gb of RAM, Ubuntu was always swapping, which makes the system slow. Since I installed Lubuntu, which is lightweight, the system now swaps less often, so my system is more pleasant to work with. KDE, Gnome and Unity are very nice and modern, but quite heavy.

Comment: @cochisebt You can Also mention MATE, which requires manual installing.

Comment: MATE is great, but quite heavy for his hardware.

Answer (score 0):

Of course he should choose a lightweight distribution.
But no matter which one he choses, he should upgrade RAM.

Btw swapping only happens, if there's not enough RAM.